# .net regex split

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a sentence like "the `$[inception]$` is an incredible movie" .and i want to split the "inception" by  seperator "`$[...]$`. I wanna know the regex pattern that actualy capable of doing that.

Comment: what patterns have you tried?

Comment: What result do you want?  `the `, `is an incredible movie`, or `the `, `inception`, `is an incredible movie`, or something else?  What should happen if you get `$[` but not `]$`, or vice versa?

Comment: I just want to get the "inception" by the seperator

Comment: It all depends on what is allowed to be between the `$[` and `]$`. Give us what you tried. SO is a place to come with problems _in_ code, not a place to ask people to _write_ the code for you.

Comment: play with it here http://regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: It is actually allowed to be word character and digits

Comment: So put a repeating character group between it that contains that, then. What exactly is your issue? If the issue is "I don't know regex", please refer to Google.

Comment: You mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/i0KKvM/1

Comment: Are you aware that `$`, `[`, and `]` are special characters?  i.e. they should be prefixed by forward slashes in order to be ecaped / handled as actual characters.  See "literal strings and backslahes": https://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html

Answer (score 1):

Regex pattern:

```regex
\$\[(.*?)\]\$
```

Sample C# code:

```cs
Regex.Match("the $[inception]$ is an incredible movie", "\\$\\[(.*?)\\]\\$").Groups[1]
```